# Buildfire: How to get Plugin Data for custom plugin?

Tags: buildfire

I created two buildfire plugins using the SDK. Added them in my plugin manager and in buildfire app. Now I want to update my plugins so as create a functionality which will navigate me to another plugin from the first one.

I followed these - [How to use Navigation](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation) and [code](https://github.com/BuildFire/folderPlugin/blob/d84551feb06cfc304c325480ca96d87795a66929/widget/widget.controller.js#L163)

and found that `buildfire.navigation.navigation` help to navigate.

Please help me to know what are these fields, how do I get value for these field for the plugin I had created.
Fields are as follow:

`pluginId, instanceId, title, folderName`

Answer (score 0):

Its best to start off knowing the difference between a `Plugin Type` and a `Plugin Instance` its the same difference between a `Class` and an `Object`
The `Plugin Type` is the blueprint of which you may create many `Plugin Instances`

That being said, each instance will have a different `id` each instance will also change its `title` and `icon` so you want to make sure you always get the latest version of this data. If you were dealing with a relational DB you would save the *Foreign Key* then `join` to the *Primary Key* to have one source of truth.

Here are the Steps you need to follow:

1. In your `control` side of the plugin. Use the
   `buildfire.pluginInstance.showDialog` ([see docs](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Plugin-Instances#buildfireplugininstanceshowdialogoptions-callback))
   This will help the app owner select which `plugin instance` you
   should navigate to. This will return back the object you need
2. (optional) If you are visually representing the they plugin's `title` or `icon` then use `dynamic data` to fetch the latest version of object
3. When you are ready to navigate pass your `plugin instance object` to `buildfire.navigation.navigateTo` ([see docs](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation#buildfirenavigationnavigateto-plugindata))

This should be all you need.
See examples in the `Folder` [Plugin](https://github.com/BuildFire/folderPlugin)